# Error: could not send registration request to daemon CLClientRegister

Tags: iphone, ios, core-location

I was getting these errors when running my App on my iphone4 in the debugger.  I did a search online and couldn't find much information besides "Restore your iphone".  I tried turning my iphone off (to try and power cycle it), but it just hung for 30 minutes with the spinning activity indicator.  I eventually did the hold both buttons forever to turn it off trick, and the phone powered off.  When I turned it back on, the phone was working as normal, no more errors when tryign to run my app, and my app launched very fast again.

A bit of background info:
1) My app only uses core location through setting mapView.showsUserLocation = TRUE;
2) I have Navigon installed
3) My App launches Navigon

I was hoping someone here might know more about this problem, and if I could potentially be causing it.  I don't want to mess my users phones up.

When I launch Navigon from my App, should I be turning off the show user location?  Could this mess things up?  I have run my App a few hundred times and never encountered any problems until this morning, and I had a problem the very first time I tried to run it this morning.  I did notice last night and this morning that I couldn't get the arrow that indicates GPS usage in the status bar to go away, and Navigon was taking forever to load, and wouldn't load half the time.

Thanks for any help, sorry to be so long winded....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never encountered this error again in the past month after hard reseting my iphone.  So if you are encountering this error that is slowing down your App launching, hard reset your iphone and hopefully the problem will go away.

To hard reset:
1) Press and hold the Home button (big circle below the screen) and the Sleep/Wake button (on top of the iPhone) simultaneously.
2) Continue holding both buttons (Ignore the "Slide to power off") until the iPhone shuts off and begins to restart.
3) You can let go of the buttons once you see the Apple logo on the screen.